# Pass multiple structs into ExecuteTemplate in Go - best practice

Tags: go, go-templates

Currently I am passing multiple structs into ExecuteTemplate, but is there a more efficient, more concise, or different way to do this?

**Go**

```
type user struct {
        Username string
        Password string
} 

type meta struct {
        Title   string
        Content string
}

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        u := getUser(w, req)
        m := meta{
                Title: "Homepage",
                Content: "Homepage meta content",
        }
        users := []user{u}
        metas := []meta{m}
        data := struct {
                User []user
                Meta []meta
        }{
                users,
                metas,
        } 
        err := tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", data)
        if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
{{range .Meta}}
    {{.Title}}
    {{.Content}}
{{end}}
```

Comment: A map literal is more concise. The benefit of the anonymous struct type is ExecuteTemplate returns an error if a field name is misspelled in the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same can be achieved more concisely using a map:

```
err := tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", map[string]interface{}{"User":[]user{u},
"Meta":[]meta{m}})
```